# flutter contact without any order

Tags: flutter, listview, contacts

I am new bee in flutter.
I have copied code from link
https://rrtutors.com/tutorials/read-contacts-from-phone-in-flutter

I am using flutter_contact dependencies.
I have created simple contact list application.
My problem is that how to  display contact which is added last
will be first in listview.  but i cant to do that.
means contacts order will be **last added will be shown
on first and other will be below.**
**means  liveview will show last feed contact on top and other will below of it **
Please help.
Thanks in advance.

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter_contact/contacts.dart';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(ReadContacts());
}

class ReadContacts extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ReadContactsState createState() => _ReadContactsState();
}

class _ReadContactsState extends State<ReadContacts> {
  List<Contact> listContacts;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // ignore: todo
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    // ignore: deprecated_member_use
    listContacts = new List();
    readContacts();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
        ),
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("Get Phone Contact List"),
            backgroundColor: Colors.green,
          ),
          body: Container(
            child: (listContacts.length > 0)
                ? ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: listContacts.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      Contact contact = listContacts.get(index);
                      return Card(
                        child: ListTile(
                            leading: CircleAvatar(
                              backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                              child: Center(
                                child: (contact.avatar != null)
                                    ? Image.memory(
                                        contact.avatar,
                                        height: 28,
                                        width: 28,
                                      )
                                    : Icon(Icons.face),
                              ),
                            ),
                            title: Text("${contact.displayName}"),
                            subtitle: Text((contact.phones.length > 0) ? "${contact.phones.get(0)}" : "No contact"),
                            trailing: InkWell(
                              child: Icon(
                                Icons.call,
                                color: Colors.green,
                              ),
                              onTap: () {
                                _makePhoneCall("tel:${contact.phones.length.gcd(0)}");
                              },
                            )),
                      );
                    })
                : Center(
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: [
                        CircularProgressIndicator(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                        ),
                        Text("reading Contacts...")
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
          ),
        ));
  }

  Future<void> _makePhoneCall(String url) async {
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }

  readContacts() async {
    final PermissionStatus permissionStatus = await _getPermission();
    if (permissionStatus == PermissionStatus.granted) {
//      Contact contact1 = ContactSortOrder.lastName();

      Contacts.streamContacts().forEach((contact) {
        print("${contact.displayName}");
        setState(() {
          listContacts.add(contact);
        });
      });
    }

  }

  //Check contacts permission
  Future<PermissionStatus> _getPermission() async {
    final PermissionStatus permission = await Permission.contacts.status;
    if (permission != PermissionStatus.granted && permission != PermissionStatus.denied) {
      final Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> permissionStatus = await [Permission.contacts].request();
      return permissionStatus[Permission.contacts] ?? PermissionStatus.undetermined;
    } else {
      return permission;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `flutter_contact` has not provides `createTime` property for `Contact` object
but it provides `lastModified`

So you can add

```
listContacts.sort((a, b) => a.lastModified.compareTo(b.lastModified));
```

in your readContact function

```
readContacts() async {
    final PermissionStatus permissionStatus = await _getPermission();
    if (permissionStatus == PermissionStatus.granted) {
//      Contact contact1 = ContactSortOrder.lastName();

      Contacts.streamContacts().forEach((contact) {
        print("${contact.displayName}");
        setState(() {
          listContacts.add(contact);
        });
      });
      listContacts.sort((b, a) => a.lastModified.compareTo(b.lastModified));
    }

  }
```

Comment: Contacts are not displayed properly.  how to sort it by crearted date time.  which dependency i have to use please guide.

Comment: Sorry I didn't find it, even Android has only LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.ContactsColumns#CONTACT_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP

Comment: And for iOS: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/16049

Comment: Please any solution which will crate query of contact database without sort order and we have to not sort  array again ?

Comment: i see one software on playstore. RECO. what logic has used there.  sending link   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67084676/flutter-contact-without-any-order?r=SearchResults